# Выгрузка документа из бота в openpyxl

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram, openpyxl

Хочу упростить жизнь коллеге и часть отчётов автоматизировать обработку. С моими задачами отлично бы справился openpyxl, но я не понимаю как поступить. Отправляю боту документ, он его кушает, но как потом начать его обрабатывать? Это вообще возможно?

```
@dp.message(content_types=['document'])
async def handle_document(message: types.Message):
        id_doc = message.document.file_id
        name_doc = message.document.file_name
        wb = load_workbook(message.document)
```

Думал что то типа такого, но это только инфа о документе, а как получить сам документ не пойму

Answer (score 0):

Скачайте его и откройте как обычно.

```
await message.document.download(destination_file=f"{message.document.file_id}")
```